# How do I get the CloudBees Database password

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

I want to access my CloudBees managed Database (MySQL) with a password from my app and client - how to I get it?

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to install the [command line tools](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK#HDownloadandconfiguretheCloudBeesSDK)

Run

```
bees db:info -p youraccount/dbname
```

and this will show all the details you need.

(-p means to show the password on the terminal, it won't by default).

If you use "bees app:bind" - or a clickstart setup your DB binding for you - your app should already be wired up to connect to the database when it runs in cloudbees (you shouldn't need to ever see the password in this case).

Comment: First install the cloudbees console http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK#HDownloadandconfiguretheCloudBeesSDK